# SQL Select values inside parenthesis

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column in my table that has the following values

```
|         loan_no                  |

|  SSS Pensioner Loan (C000000001) |
|  SSS SSS Loan (C000000002)       |
|  SSS Salary Loan (C000000007)    |
|  SSS PAGIBIG Loan (C000000003)   |
```

How can I select only the values inside the parenthesis
to have an outcome like this:

```
|  loan_no    |

|  C000000001 |
|  C000000002 |
|  C000000007 |
|  C000000003 |
```

Thank You in advance :)
I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: SQL can do this, but you should think about changing your database design.   What have you tried so far?   Look into CharIndex and Substring for starters.

Comment: SUBSTRING and PATINDEX/CHARINDEX, or better to handle display issues in a more appropriate code layer.

Answer (score 8):

CHARINDEX will help you [Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b4cf5c0b-de2e-4c3d-8dbc-19178fe8ced3/tsql-query-to-read-data-between-brackets?forum=transactsql)

```
declare @temp table        
(val nvarchar(77))

insert into @temp values ('SSS Pensioner Loan (C000000001)')
insert into @temp values ('SSS SSS Loan (C000000002)      ')
insert into @temp values ('SSS Salary Loan (C000000007)   ')
insert into @temp values ('SSS PAGIBIG Loan (C000000003)  ')



SELECT 
SUBSTRING(val,CHARINDEX('(', val) + 1,CHARINDEX(')', val) - CHARINDEX('(', val) - 1) as Val
from @temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
declare @table table (loan nvarchar(100))
insert into @table
select 'SSS Pensioner Loan (C000000001)'
union all select 'SSS SSS Loan (C000000002)'   
union all  select 'SSS Salary Loan (C000000007)'   
  union all select 'SSS PAGIBIG Loan (C000000003)'


  select substring (loan,CHARINDEX('(', loan)+1,CHARINDEX(')', loan)-CHARINDEX('(', loan)-1)
  from @table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  substring and instr function for mysql (for sql server you can use charindex in place of instr) follows:

```
SELECT Substring(loan_no, INSTR(loan_no, '(') + 1,
       INSTR(loan_no, ')') -
              INSTR(loan_no, '(') - 1) AS
       loan_no,
       INSTR(loan_no, ')')
       AS loan_no
FROM   Table
```