# Extract each string between each set of two different strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

If I have for example the string:

```
'x(abc),y(def),z(ghi)'
```

How can I extract out either a comma delimited string:

```
'abc,def,ghi'
```

or a table of the strings:

```
'abc'
'def'
'ghi'
```

that exist between the two strings `'('` and `')'`?

They are comma delimited, but each 'element' can be of variable length.

Comment: Are you storing multiple values in a cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If open to a TVF.  Being a TVF, it is easy to use in a `CROSS APPLY` if your data is in a table.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'x(abc),y(def),z(ghi)'

Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](@S,'(',')')
```

**Returns**

```
RetSeq  RetPos  RetVal
1       3       abc
2       10      def
3       17      ghi
```

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   as (Select 1 From (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   as (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   as (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) as (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  ( Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) From cte4 ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1
)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Comment: You need to put that on Git with a good readme file explaining it lol

Comment: @scsimon Thanks for the grin :)

Comment: Well I don't understand it but it works as a black box! What's the Max Length? 1MM characters?

Comment: @TDP Just a comment / note to myself.  We create an ad-hoc tally table with a max of 1MM rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `charindex` like below:

```
declare @temp table        
(val nvarchar(50))

insert into @temp values ('x(abc)')
insert into @temp values ('y(def)')
insert into @temp values ('z(ghi)')

SELECT 
SUBSTRING(val,CHARINDEX('(', val) + 1,CHARINDEX(')', val) - CHARINDEX('(', val) - 1) as Val
from @temp
```

Ref: [SQL Select values inside parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35308399/sql-select-values-inside-parenthesis)

EDIT: if it is one row including many values inside paranthesis, you need to split it based on comma first. For SQL 2008, I am using the split function specified in this link for years, thanks Andy: [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string)

Create the function below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

And see this: `SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstring('x(abc),y(def),z(ghi)')`

This way, you can split your data based on comma and use the first charindex strategy I mentioned.

Comment: I think they only have 1 row of data not 3

Comment: I use a similar parse/split function in the past.  I was shocked at the performance gains in using the tally or xml approach.

Comment: I’d upgrade to a non loop method but this answer isn’t incorrect :). http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've selected the other one though as it's not actually '(' and ')' that act as the delimiters, and I'd prefer not to use a loop as the actual string can be really long.